# Why in some sites I cannot find any hat?

Tags: discussion

Some users in many sites wear hats. But it seems in some other sites like Math.SE there to be no hat. So I'm curious about why.

Comment: They probably did not want any math hatter jokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hats are not compulsory.

Some sites didn't sign up to have hats.

Even if a site did sign up you can opt out.

Answer (score 3):

Some sites opted out of the Winterbash, and noone earned hats on such sites.

You'll have to ask the moderators of Math.SE themselves for their reasoning.

Comment: Some per-site metas have questions such as [Do we want Hats?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/do-we-want-hats) on [programmers.se]; I don't see one on meta [math.se] though